# Source in the Torah that the entire Torah is immutable

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach

The title pretty much says it all. But I am looking for a *posuk* that states that all contained in the Torah applies forever and for all generations, and cannot be changed, etc.

I am pretty sure that such a posuk exists, but I have only been able to find ones that mention the immutability of a particular ordinance — not the whole book.

Any help?